# What does it mean when cluster label is -1?

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, dbscan

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
model = DBSCAN(eps=3.3, leaf_size=5, min_samples=3)
y_pred = model.fit_predict(df)
```

my silhouette score is

```
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
silhouette_score(df, y_pred)
```

output

```
0.4432857434946073
```

However, my labels are as so

code:

```
set(model.labels_)
```

output:

```
{-1, 0}
```

What does cluster `-1` and `0` mean, and how do I right this?

note: I don't know if this is important, but

```
df.head()
```

output:

```
Gender      Age      education  satisfaction    salary  performance 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0   0.0     0.446350    -1.010909   -0.891688   1.153254    -0.108350   
1   1.0     1.322365    -0.147150   -1.868426   -0.660853   -0.291719   
2   1.0     0.008343    -0.887515   -0.891688   0.246200    -0.937654   
3   0.0     -0.429664   -0.764121   1.061787    0.246200    -0.763634   
4   1.0     -1.086676   -0.887515   -1.868426   -0.660853   -0.644858
```

As you can see, my data is multidimensional, and I can't reduce the dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html), -1 stands for noise: points alone in their cluster. This means points that have less than `min_sample` neighbors in the `eps` neighbourhood.

Here you have a single cluster (0) and some noise (points with label -1).

If you expected more clusters you should tweak `eps` and `min_samples`

Comment: Thanks. I will use more min_samples. However, should I use less eps or more eps? When I plotted the optimal number of epsilons for DBSCAN (see: https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-clustering-dbscan-determine-the-optimal-value-for-epsilon-eps-python-example-3100091cfbc ), I get something like 2.5

Comment: It all depends on how many clusters you are expecting ! But If you get a single non-noisy cluster, eps is probably too large and/or min_samples too small

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I am trying to analyse this dataset right now https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/pavansubhasht/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset , and all I'm getting is a single cluster with lots of noisy values. Thus, I have a single cluster (0) with the noise (-1). I tried to increase/decrease eps and min_samples, but nope, it's still like that (0) and (-1). What would you do next, if this happened to you?

Comment: I would compute the distances in between the individuals rows of your dataset to check what order of magnitude they are. Maybe you should try with a single column to test it, then you can use the whole dataset ;)